# Cant Change page layout after Import-SPWeb

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I can no longer change the page layout for any pages in page edit mode (the option is not even there) after running an Import-SPWeb from a back up from staging. I can't even go into edit mode and then click save. I get this error.

Invalid SPListItem. The SPListItem provided is not compatible with a Publishing Page.

Any ideas?

SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll never guess what fixed this problem for me.

I went to the Pages list settings. There was a content type in there that I didn't need anymore so I tried to delete it. Got an error message saying that my content type was read only.

After those exact manipulations, everything started to work again.

This worked in 2 environments.

They should put this in the certification exam!